# Is there a faster method to use a 2d numpy array of booleans to select elements from a 2d array, but with a 2d output?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

If I have an array like this

```
arr=np.array([['a','b','c'],
              ['d','e','f']])
```

and an array of booleans of the same shape, like this:

```
boolarr=np.array([[False,True,False],
                  [True,True,True]])
```

I want to be able to only select the elements from the first array, that correspond to a True in the boolean array. So the output would be:

```
out=[['b'],
     ['d','e','f']]
```

I managed to solve this with a simple for loop

```
out=[]
for n, i in enumerate(arr):
    out.append(i[boolarr[n]])
    out=np.array(out)
```

but the problem is this solution is slow for large arrays, and was wondering if there was an easier solution with numpys indexing. Just using the normal notation `arr[boolarr]` returns a single flat array `['b','d','e','f']`. I also tried using a slice with `arr[:,[True,False,True]]`, which keeps the shape but can only use one boolean array.

Comment: Your resulting array is not a valid shape for a numeric dtype, it would have to be object, at which point, you might as well use a list

Comment: Let's say you get the `out` list of lists in a timely fashion.  Then what?  What do you plan to do with it?  Using such a list is bound to be as slow as generating it.

Comment: If you could use a padded array instead, e.g. `np.array([['b','',''],['d','e','f']])` we could suggest a relatively fast way of distributing those `arr[boolarr]` values.  But you/we need a clearer idea of what you really need.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments. I misunderstood how an array works. For those curious this is my solution (I'm actually working with numbers):

```
arr[boolarr]=np.nan
```

And then I just changed how the rest of the function handles nan values